# Django - ModelForm does not save because of missing user id

Tags: django

I get:

```
IntegrityError at /category/
NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions_category.user_id
```

here in my view:

```
    elif "create" in request.POST:
        createform = CategoryForm(data=request.POST)
        createform.save(commit=False)
        createform.user = request.user
        createform.save() <--- specifically here, the .save with commit=False goes through and I can also set the user
```

I checked with the debugger and createform.user has a User, that User also has an id.

forms.py:

```
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        exclude = ["subcategory", "user"]
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subcategory = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

User import is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Why will it not save? I set the user before calling .save(), the user is set (and has an id) as far as I can tell with the debugger?

I have run both manage.py migrate and manage.py makemigrations and everything is up to date.

Edit:

the template:

```
<p>Create new category form</p>
<form action="/category/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ createform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create new category">
</form>
<hr>
```

The creation and saving of new Category objects worked before I added the "user" field to the model (and I ran migrate and makemigrations after I did)

Edit 2:
complete view:

```
def category_view(request):
    createform = CategoryForm()
    searchform = CategorySearchForm()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    categories_left = []
    categories_right = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        if "search" in request.POST:
            categories_left = Category.objects.for_title(request.POST["left-search"], user=request.user)
            categories_right = Category.objects.for_title(request.POST["right-search"], user=request.user)
        elif "create" in request.POST:
            createform = CategoryForm(request.POST)
            if createform.is_valid():
                createform.save(commit=False)
                createform.user = request.user
                createform.save()
        elif "add-subcategory" in request.POST:
            left = Category.objects.for_id(request.POST["left-category"], user=request.user)
            right = Category.objects.for_id(request.POST["right-category"], user=request.user)
            try:
                left.subcategory.add(right)
                old = left
                old.pk = None
                old.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                print("This combination already exists.") # TODO
    context = {"createform":createform, 
               "searchform":searchform,
               "categories":categories,
               "categories_left":categories_left,
               "categories_right":categories_right}
    return render(request, "transactions/category_creation.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save passing an instance of user.

```
createform.save(commit=False)
createform.instance.user = request.user
createform.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The form's save method returns an instance. You should update and save the instance, rather than trying to save the form again.

```
instance = createform.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user
instance.save()
```